# Requiring users to populate a field

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

I have a snippet in PowerShell that reads questions from a flat file and prompts the user to provide a boolean or string response (i.e. Do you like flying cars? Why do you like skydiving?). All answers are written to a .xls for consumption to a DB later.

I can make the script repeat question for users that do not select a boolean answer (i.e. A, B, C or "Yes", "No"). However getting a user to provide a string (short) answer) is a bit more trickier.

```
$Question7 = Get-Content -path $PSScriptRoot\src\Question7.txt -raw

Write-Host $Question7 -ForegroundColor Yellow
$reason_for_hobby = Read-Host -Prompt "Please write in the answer"
Writ-Host "Answer: $reason_for_hobby" -ForegroundColor Green

Add-Member -inputObject $infoObject -memberType NoteProperty -name "HBYREASON" - 
value $reason_for_hobby
```

I am trying to figure out how to force users to provide at least a 215 character response, and to repeat the question if one is not provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with a simple `while`-loop (While `$reason_for_hobby` has less than 215 characters repeate):

```
while ($reason_for_hobby.Length -lt 215){
    $reason_for_hobby = Read-Host -Prompt "Please write in the answer"
}
```

However better would be a `do-while`-loop if the variable `$reason_for_hobby` is not initialized before (do this once and repeate while `$reason_for_hobby` has less than 215 characters):

```
do{
    $reason_for_hobby = Read-Host -Prompt "Please write in the answer"
}while ($reason_for_hobby.Length -lt 215)
```

Comment: Don't know if the comment was somehow deleted or it didn't save. I wanted to thank you for the help. It worked fantastically!